# Nginx, include file not work

Tags: nginx

I want to `include` my custom directory like this:

`include /User/dulin/workspoace/nginx-winter/demo-2/servers/*;`

but not working.

but put my `server1` and `server2` files into the default directory `/usr/local/etc/nginx/servers`, and use `include servers/*`, it works.

why? How do I use my custom directory?

Comment: Put your config file here

Comment: @Vyacheslav sorry, it works. I found the problem , there is a error in path.

`include /Users/dulin/workspace/nginx-winter/demo-2/servers/*;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is about wrong typing 'workspace' 
 You wrote 'workspoace'. Check